# Saving numbers in activity to use again later

Tags: android

In the last activity of my app there is some numbers displayed in edit text's and an option to add more to these totals, the add more button takes you back to start of the app, where the user does the same thing again inputs some numbers and ends up back on last activity.

What I want to do is if they press the add more button is save the numbers that are in the edit text's so I can add them to the new set of numbers coming in.

What I thinking is save the numbers in on Pause, but don't know how and then add them to new numbers in on Resume, am I on the right track, what is the best way to do this.

Comment: Read about http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "source" activity do this:

```
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(
"yourfilename.bla", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

editor.putString("key", value);
editor.commit();
```

In the target activity do this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(
"yourfilename.bla", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String value= preferences.getString("key", "");
```

The second parameter in getString is the default value you want returned if "key" isn't found.

Also Check these links

[Android Using SharedPreferences to save and retrieve values - Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872032/android-using-sharedpreferences-to-save-and-retrieve-values-counter)

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/01/use-getsharedpreferences-to-retrieve.html

Comment: Hi the source activity and target activity will be the same, I want to save numbers on that activity, send user back to start of app and when the user ends back up on this activity, I want to add the saved numbers to the new numbers. I'm getting problem when i try put double its saying the method put double is undefined for this type of sharedpreference editor. put int is working

Answer (score 2):

You can use Intent to do so. For example if you want to transfer an int.

```
  //first activity
  Intent intent =  new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("myInt", number);

  //Second Activity
  Intent intent =  this.getIntent();
  int number = intent.getExtra("myInt", -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing onSaveInsance and onRestoreInstance of the activity. This would be called before onPause and before onResume.

Sample is [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/09/onsaveinstancestate-and.html).

Also, to add the data from a different activity which would return to this activity then you can use the startActivityForResult and send the data as intent from the new activity before finishing..

Answer (score 1):

you'd better use SharedPreferences....
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score -1):

You can use startActivityForResult and send your data via Intent.